# mysqli, sha1/salt password valid check

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm creating a login form.Validating user input to check whether the email format is correct and password is longer than 6 chars, if these are valid then check whether the login
credentials are valid and they match with email/password stored on the users table.At the registration form I'm encrypting the password using sha1 and a given salt. When I check if
the password is correct I write the same check but even though I enter the correct login 
credentials it seems impossible to validate login. So here's my code:
User login function:

```
function user_login($email, $password){
    global $db;
    $salt='%#@#@**#_-!';
    $userid = id_from_email($email);
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $password  = sha1($password.$salt);
    $query="SELECT UserId FROM users WHERE Email= '".$email."' and UserPass= '".$password."' ";
    $result=$db->query($query);
    $valid = $result->num_rows;
    return ($valid >1) ? $userid : false;
}
```

And here is the part of login.php that checks if the login is valid:

```
else if(empty($errors) == true) {
        $userlogin=user_login($email, $password);
        if ($userlogin==false){
        $errors[]='Wrong email/password combination.';
        } else {
        //set the user session
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['UserId']=$userlogin;
        header('Location:success.php');
        }
```

No matter if I put the right password and email. It always outputs "Wrong email/pass combination"
And here is how I store the pass in the database on register.php

```
$salt='%#@#@**#_-!';
$password = sha1($password.$salt);
```

I'd be very grateful if you could help me out.

Thankyou.

Comment: Off-topic: password salt should always be random; the purpose of the salt is to have different hashes for the same password, so if one account has their password compromised, other accounts with the same password will have a different hash and would not be distinguishable as having the same password. Also, `sha1()` is not a good password hashing algorithm, ideally you want a **very slow** hash algorithm, so brute-forcing would take looong time.

Comment: if the password is compromized, the same password will work for other accounts with the same password, no matter how much salt you add. I think a salt is their for attackers that gain access to the database. Without a salt, they could just replace the hash in the table and access the website with their own password. Now they have to guess the salt (or look it up here on stackoverflow :p)...

Comment: @WouterH Yes, it will work, but you will have no way to figure which accounts use the same password. If you manage to get your hands on the hashed passwords, it would be obvious which ones use the same password if they are unsalted.

Comment: But if you want different salts for different users, you'll have to store the random salt in the user table... makes it more easy to figure out the salt, no?

Comment: So if I generate a new salt for each user and save it on the users table what would be the point of it?  If the cracker gets access to the hashed passwords he can also access the invividual salts too, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is  this:

```
return ($valid >= 1) ? $userid : false;
```

instead of

```
return ($valid > 1) ? $userid : false;
```

unless you expect that at least 2 rows should match the given email and password hash.

And I would prefer this:

```
return ($valid == 1) ? $userid : false;
```

Comment: Thank you. Silly mistake... So it works now, I remember having the 
value $valid==1, but dont know why I changed it. Thanks it works now.

Comment: If I'd use $valid == 1, than I should modify the query to fetch that value and compare it. At the moment the query returns the number of rows not the value of the row.

Comment: You would use $valid == 1 because you want to be sure that only 1 row (so one user) matches the credentials. If there are 2 or more users that match to the same credentials, somethings fishy is going on.

Comment: Btw: if this was an answer to your question, it would be nice if you marked it as an answer, thank you.

Comment: Thank you I  am relatively new to stackoverflow and I forget about marking the right question.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the call to the database with the appropriate email variable:

```
$query="SELECT UserId FROM users WHERE Email= '".$useremail."' and UserPass= '".$password."' ";
```

Comment: Hello Yan. In fact I changed useremail to email just to ease peoples reading. But I have the same values. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Please do `var_dump($email);`, `var_dump($password);` after the line `$password  = sha1($password.$salt);` and post the values here.

Comment: I added these two lines but when I enter the correct email/pass it still says "wrong email pass" and another line:
string(18) "er@gmail.com" string(40) "01f5a00b09702f0be2850123c49e69650c9937cc"

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the `UserId` from the database, but never actually use that result; your `user_login()` function returns the result of `id_from_email($email)` and not the ID received from the database. Check your `id_from_email()` return value, or better yet — return the ID from the database query instead.

Comment: So you're suggesting me to do something like:
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
$userid=$row['UserId'];
and then return $userid ? :)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am suggesting. Unless your database's `UserId` column has nothing to do with the IDs of your users, which I find highly unlikely.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. In fact I dunno why the heck I had in mind when I created the id_from_username function....THANK YOU FOR YOUR SUGGESTION.